# Should all assemblies target the same architecture?

Tags: .net, x86-64, cefsharp

Some third party libraries, like `CefSharp`, requires to set architecture to `x86` or `x64`, but not `Any CPU`. Does this apply to all projects in solution, or just the "start up" one?

Generally, is `x86` for start up project and `Any CPU` for all other (but not x64 obviously) a valid configuration, and thus all is running in 32-bit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *deployment* detail.  You should create two installers, one for a 32-bit operating system and one for a 64-bit operating system.  The user picks which ever one is appropriate for his machine.

The 64-bit installer should deploy the 64-bit version of the CefSharp executables.  All assemblies are simply compiled to AnyCPU.

The 32-bit installer should deploy the 32-bit version of CefSharp.  All assemblies are *still* compiled to AnyCPU.  But you can cover the corner case where a user with a 64-bit OS prefers to use the 32-bit version of your program for some reason.  Simply do so by setting the "Prefer 32-bit" option on your EXE project.  Or pick x86 as the Platform target on older VS versions.  Other assemblies stay at AnyCPU.

If you don't want to bother supporting both then the last one works for any user.

Comment: CefSharp uses native C++ dlls that are platform-specific, so the .NET assembly would need to match whatever platform the deployed dlls use.

Answer (score 2):

The reason CefSharp requires you to choose x86 or x64 is because it relies on native C++ DLLs to provide the CEF/Chromium browser. There is no such AnyCPU concept in native DLLs. So Visual Studio need to know whether to copy the 32-bit or 64-bit CEF DLLs into your bin directory when you build and debug.

To answer your specific questions:

Only setting the platform on the startup project is fine. Everything else can stay on AnyCPU.

Generally this configuration is OK. It means that your program will only ever work in 32-bit mode. When deploying, you only need to include the 32-bit versions of the CefSharp and CEF binary files (libcef.dll, etc.) that are in your bin\x86\Release directory.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mix an x64 and x86 libraries you are fine. If one of your libraries is x86 and the rest are Any CPU you are fine.